# What java design pattern to avoid casting data entity

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm currently implementing asynchronous-like event queue inside my application - it is designed to work like this: one component reacts to some user input and putting event to the queue, and another "listener" is checking whether there is event of specific type inside the queue and run it's own business logic

There can be various event types (like USER_MOUSE_CLICK, USER_KEYBOARD_CLICK etc) and every implementation has it's own "event-object" type

It looks like this (I'm ommiting constructors - setting all fields and getters/setters - they are just normal default ones):

```
public abstract MyEvent<T> {
    private EventType eventType;
    private T eventData;
}

public MouseClickEvent extends MyEvent<ClickPoint> { // ClickPoint class contains x,y of mouse click
    public MouseClick(ClickPoint point) {
        super(EventType.USER_MOUSE_CLICK, point);
    }
}

public KeyboardClickEvent extends MyEvent<String> { // character that has been clicked on keyboard
    public MouseClick(String key) {
        super(EventType.USER_KEYBOARD_CLICK, key);
    }
}
```

I have also a service with queue of `MyEvent` instances and the method to retrieve first event of provided `EventType` if exists - it's look like

```
...
private List<MyEvent> queue;
...
public MyEvent fetchMyEvent(EventType eventType) {
    for(MyEvent event : queue) {
        if(event.getEventType().equals(eventType) {
            return event;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
...
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to retrieve the event I need to cast it to specific implementation like

```
// some listener logic
MouseClickEvent event = (MouseClickEvent ) eventService.fetchMyEvent(EventType.USER_MOUSE_CLICK);
log("The X point of mouse click was: " + event.getEventData().x);
```

I don't like this casting - I feel like I have no control of a types when I'm fetching events and I see this situation like a 'weak point' and bug generator. Is there any design pattern to avoid this, or should I redesign whole system? Or maybe this is the only way and I should not care

Comment: At some point you will need the conrete class of your event object to access its object values. You can use **if(myEventObj instanceof MouseClickEvent)** to check that it can be casted to a MouseClickEvent. You may skip your event handling process if the expected event is not the event you have received.

Comment: It's ok, becase your listener already knows which event types it can process and which it cannot. 
E.g. `PrintCharacterOnKeyDownListener` have nothing to do with `MouseDragEvent`.

Comment: Andreas Hauschild - using `instanceof` gives me nothing but error handling - I can have the same with `try{}catch()` however I realised that I can implement `fetchMyEvent` method to accept as second parameter the desired class (like `fetchMyEvent(USER_MOUSE_CLICK, MouseClickEvent .class)` and return event only if `instanceof` provided type - maybe this is the solution

Comment: Since you are already passing `EventType` to the fetch function, I think you are better off with casting in this case since you know exactly what type are getting (by design). Otherwise visitor pattern as provided in the answer is usually the way but it's a bit of complex pattern. In this case typecasting is probably the better option.

Comment: Create a separate event queue for each type of event.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you the visitor pattern to avoid cast. You are right casting should be used with precaution.

To use visitor pattern you have to :
first: define the visitor interface:

```
public interface IEventVisitor {

    void visit(MouseClickEvent event);

    void visit(KeyboardClickEvent event);

}
```

Second in your supper class define an absract method accept as:

```
public abstract MyEvent<T> {
    private EventType eventType;
    private T eventData;

    public abstract void accept(IEventVisitor visitor);
}
```

Third: implement the method for each subclass as:

```
public MouseClickEvent extends MyEvent<ClickPoint> { // ClickPoint class contains x,y of mouse click
    public MouseClick(ClickPoint point) {
        super(EventType.USER_MOUSE_CLICK, point);
    }

    public void accept(IEventVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);

    }
}
```

And finally implement your visitor interface.

The use will be like the following, instantiate the visitor and call event.accept(visitor).

```
Event event = eventService.fetchMyEvent(EventType.USER_MOUSE_CLICK);
IEventVisitor visitor = new IEventVisitor() {

            @Override
            public void visit(MouseClickEvent event) {
                // logic goes here
            }

            @Override
            public void visit(KeyboardClickEvent event) {
                // logic goes here
            }
        };


event.accept(visitor);
```

Comment: Seems like a better comment than answer.

Comment: could you please provide at least example of how would you see this implementation? Ofc I'm not saying about full code implementation - just description

Comment: ok I see your edit - thank you for this. Unfortunately what you are proposing is to move business logic to the event object which seems to be very bad idea. Also it would mean that I cannot use one event type in two listeners (like one listener for logging user activity and second for drawing circle where user clicked). I could provide from the listener some anonymous implementation of let say `Executor` interface with `execute()` method but to create this instance I need to know on what type of `eventData` I'm operating *in the listener* - so casting again :)

Comment: No the business logic will not be moved to the event object but to the class implementing visitor, you can visit your object by defferent maner using multiple implementation of the visitor interface

Comment: yes you are right - but still I think that it limits me to only one way of how to use the specific type of event